# Multilabel Classification Task using SVM

Tags: svm, multi-class, multilabel

I want to classify diabetic retinopathy grades (normal, mild, moderate, severe, PDR) using SVM.

But the problem is i don't know which type of svm should i use, because i extract three lession features (MA, HM, and EX), and sometimes one image can contain all of these lession but just belong to one class (ex:severe).

Can someone enlighten me should i use multiclass/multilabel SVM in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this here since I do not have reputation to comment.

The question requires some more clarity on the following statement.

> But the problem is i don't know which type of svm should i use, because i extract three lession features (MA, HM, and EX)

You will need to provide more information to set the context of your problem.

For now I will assume you are using a single task - single model setting which basically means that you have one feature set and a single model. The model will try to learn that feature set and make predictions.

Now if you are only concerned about the multiclass vs multilabel then the only question you should be asking is will any of you samples ever fall into multiple classes (normal, mild, moderate, severe, PDR), that is can a sample fall into 2 classes say **normal,mild** (you need to decide if this makes sense)?

If the answer to that question is "No" then https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multiclass-classification

If the answer to that question is "Yes" then https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification

Additional Reference:

- Multitask Classification : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification

Comment: thanks for your helpful information, i think the answer is no, because one image only have one classes, it's impossible if one image can have 2 classes

but here i want to clarify, i segment my image for 3 lession (MA, HM, and EX) so the output will have 3 images contain 3 different lession, from that segmented images, i extract features such as area, GLCM, etc, and after that, the extracted feature (in csv format) will be the input to svm, which in my case have 5 classes

here's my reference paper, but the description is similar to multiclass : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9328438

Comment: Now even though you have 3 images that contain different information, at the end of the day you extract features from those images and turn it into one single feature set (the extracted features in csv format). This feature set is then used to train a single svm model, so my above answer holds and based on your comment you are doing Multi class Classification(in fact you could have more than 5 classes, as long as one sample in your data can have only one corresponding class, it is multi class classification).